# How to capture the countdown timer and pass it to a php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a quiz app that need to store the duration from the countdown timer. I tried many solutions but still can't find the right way to do it! What I need exactly is when the submit button is clicked a function will stop the countdown and capture the timer, then send it to another PHP page with POST method or whatever.

Thanks in advance.

---

```js
   function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
            setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.text("00 : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);

                if (timer < 10) {
                    audio.play();
                }

                if (--timer < 0) {
                    window.location.href = "test.php";
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        jQuery(function ($) {
            var examtime = 60 * 1,
                display = $('#time');
            startTimer(examtime, display);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
  <div><span id="time">00 : 01 : 00</span></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show your attempt(s) along with the corresponding result(s).

Comment: you could just capture it with jquery, and send it with ajax to you php script - or you could make the timer a part of the form, or you could create a session and store it, or you could .... etc etc etc

Comment: @Stender Can you show me one of these exemples please!

Comment: This method would allow for clientside manipulation. I would track the counter on the server to prevent any shenanigans. You can use the client side to start the timer on the server via ajax. David Walsh has a php timer class you could base yours off of: https://davidwalsh.name/php-timer-benchmark

Comment: @PatrickQ I tried to use input rather than h1 so that I can extract the timer with POST method but didn't work! <input type=text name=countdown id=timer value=00:00:00>

Comment: @M.Eddamoun  Please don't just tell us that you tried things that didn't work.  _Show us_.  You said "I tried many solutions".  Please _show_ these attempts in your question and describe the result and how it differs from the desired result.  The most appropriate solution will very well depend on the rest of your application architecture, so us blindly writing a solution for you from scratch is not a good use of anyone's time.  It is better for us to help you fix your existing code.

Comment: @wrxsti Thanks, I will ckeck it now.

Comment: First off, I totally agree that this is a bad way to do it. The users could easily just change the numbers if they know basic html.... that said - modified your code a bit here. : https://jsfiddle.net/r1Lksmqx/

Comment: As Patrick Q says, blindly giving you the answer is likely to end up wasting our time and yours. Due to the way you've framed the question I'm assuming you aren't very familiar with event listeners, and XHR requests. Check out the following, try a few things, and come back with examples if you still have questions. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ - https://api.jquery.com/click/ - https://davidwalsh.name/php-timer-benchmark

Comment: One thing that can be noted too is that `setInterval` does not guarantee a full precision for the timing, even if in your case that may not be noticeable, for longer timers it can show

Comment: Hi new contributor! I edited your question, removed the jsfiddle and used SO snippen functionality. Links are generally discouraged since SO has snippet functionality. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information, and this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: On the other hand, i would like to gently tug 1K+ rep users to answer the question, if questions showed/mentioned bad practices, show good practices in the answer.

Comment: @Danilo wouldn't the relatively helpful comments on here warrant enough for him to attempt a full and complete question?

Comment: @Danilo Thanks man! This made the code more clear.

Comment: @M.Eddamoun no problem. After you gain some rep you will have access to Review queue and you can then help other users too :D

Comment: @wrxsti yes, but not independent. You need to think about other users who will search this question. So primary concert is answering the question, secondary is helping the community.

Comment: @Danilo Thank you so much! your comments was really helpful for me btw :) Since I'm still a beginner I expected such comments, but it's ok. One more thing: should I change my code to work on the server side rather than client side?

Comment: @M.Eddamoun Ok you are new user... so you don't know this, and it  might seem cold. But keep the topic of the question. Server side/Client side sub question isn't beneficial to this topic. This is Question and Answer community, not a forum. Keep your questions at a single topic. After you fix this problem you are having, then you can ask another one. Think about other users who will search for your question, they don't need extra information such as discusion. For everything else you can visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/. :D

Comment: @Stender Thanks, it worked! For security, I know it's not a good idea but this is just for learning porpuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed! I had to add a function that pass the value to an input. In addition, disabled inputs don't get submitted, so you have change them to a hidden input. Also, Added this line: $("form").attr("action"); to submit form after taking the value.

```js
   function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
            setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.text("00 : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);

                if (--timer < 0) {
                    window.location.href = "test.php";
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        jQuery(function ($) {
            var examtime = 60 * 1,
                display = $('#timer');
            startTimer(examtime, display);
        });
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitButton").click(function(){
                var theValueToUse =           jQuery('#timer').text();
                jQuery('#theValue').val(theValueToUse);
                $("form").attr("action");
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="theForm" action="test.php" method="POST">
  <div><span id="timer">00 : 01 : 00</span></div>
  <!-- make it hidden -->
  <input id="theValue" name="theValue" value="" type="text">
  <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, timer is a variable inside a function, JS has function scope, so you can't reach it. If you declare the variable outside the function, timer will be accessed from everywhere, it will have global scope. Its not a good practice to pollute the global scope, but this will work if this is a simple JS. After that , use JQuery ajax to send that that data to the PHP, timer will be available, delete that form.